# Android Media player refresh on click

Tags: java, android, multithreading, button, media-player

In my layout I have 6 buttons.  I want to play a sound whenever each button is clicked -  different sound for every button. I created an array of 6 Media Players (one for each button).

When a button is clicked, I want to play the corresponding sound.  If another sound is playing after a previous button click, I want that sound to stop and then the sound corresponding to this button to start playing  form the beginning.

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId()==clickPaths.get(ButtonPresentMoment)){
            ButtonPresentMoment++;
            //Error is in this for loop.
            for(int i =0;i<MediaPlayers.length;i++){
                MediaPlayers[i].pause();
                if(MediaPlayers[i].getCurrentPosition()!=0)
                MediaPlayers[i].seekTo(0);
            }
            MediaPlayers[v.getId()].start();
            Score+=Level;
            ShowNextLevel();
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,EndGameActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Score",Score);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rewrote the question using better English grammar.

Comment: i can't write english very well i am sorry . But what i wanna do is that when i press a button , media player starts . After that i press a button too , if media player isn't finish i wanna stop it and starts new button's sound .

Answer (score 0):

You need to release the media player. Use this code to stop previous music.

```
MediaPlayers[i].release();
```